# Annoyance running Ant build in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA v. 12.1.4, Community Edition.

Every time I run an Ant build from the "Ant Build" menu, the IDE opens my `build.xml` file, stealing focus and covering up whatever I was working on.  This is driving me crazy.  Other developers in my group don't experience the same behavior.

Is there a setting somewhere to configure/disable this?

**Update** I noticed that it happens with any command that calls my compile target, and it places focus on the `javac` line.  Here is the task:

```
<target
        name="compile-source"
        depends="-init">
    <delete dir="${out.source.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${out.source.dir}"/>
    <javac                                   
            destdir="${out.source.dir}"
            includeantruntime="false"
            debug="true">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:all"/>
        <src path="${in.source.dir}"/>
        <src path="${in.shared.source.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="source.compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you run your ant command?  Are you double clicking on it?

Comment: I've tried double clicking, right clicking and running target, and assigning keyboard shortcuts.  All produce the same behavior.

Comment: Are you running Ultimate or Community? (not sure if it matters though)

Comment: Community (updated question)

Comment: Thanks - I'm unable to reproduce the issue in Ultimate, trying community now...

Comment: What happens if you set `debug` to false?

Comment: No luck with setting debug to false or removing the debug attribute all together.

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce the issue. Can you please post the properties window for your ant build? You should have 4 separate tabs. Make sure you are clicking on the properties for the task that your running when the issue occurs.

Comment: The settings mirror mine which is working as expected. I'd try the following: Checkout a new revision from source control if possible and if that doesn't work than install a fresh copy of IDEA. There may be an issue with the settings file in IDEA, but I'm not sure what at this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar issue was [reported some time ago](http://ru-intellijidea.livejournal.com/46943.html?thread=244575#t244575) in the IntelliJ IDEA Russian community.

It turned out to be a hidden setting in the XML (which has no UI right now but some older EAP build could trigger it because of a bug).

You should check `.idea/workspace.xml` file in the project root for this:

```
<component name="antWorkspaceConfiguration">
    <option name="IS_AUTOSCROLL_TO_SOURCE" value="true">
```

Changing the value to `false` should fix the problem. Make sure IDEA is not running when you perform this modification.